# Telerik - ASP.NET Multiple WYSIWYG issue

Tags: asp.net, telerik, wysiwyg, radeditor

Using RadEditor (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/custommodules/defaultcs.aspx), when placing two of them on one page the following occurs:

The first one works perfectly.
The second one works but when styling or doing anything to it the HTML source is full of only plain text, no styling whatsoever.

Is there an issue using two RadEditor's with the one control even if they are uniquely named?
What possible solutions could I implement to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what is the code that is causing the problem? Copying over several editors from the demo you linked has them working properly with me. Check your implementation for global variables or weird names (in function, variables, the module itself, etc).

Comment: Thanks, it was a global var issue! :)